# Why the ng-change event not firing when the value field of input is changed from session

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my jspx file, I am writing like this. Now the value attribute is getting changed and I can see the text box with new value but ng-change is not firing when value is changed because ${sessionScope.counter} is changed.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="review.Rating" ng-change="change(review.Rating)" value="${sessionScope.counter}" />
```

PN: I have loaded Angular propery and other things within the controller are working properly.

Comment: create a plunker or jsfiddle

Comment: Its something with session, plunker ?

Answer (score -1):

If you are changing "value" it wont fire ngChange(). Just like onchange().

ng-change will trigger correctly when user type a value in the input field. It will not triggered when user type several chars and press select a value

See from angularjs for input[text]
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D

You can read there ng-change details as "**Angular expression to be executed when input changes due to user interaction with the input element**"

Comment: This is not a solution, rather a comment. I know this, as input event is not getting triggered so ng-change is not getting fired.